# Google Push Notification for send data

Tags: android, push-notification

When I change data value from one android device, I will *send this data value to server*.

Then this value should be changed on  every android devices simultaneously.

I am trying to make **synchronized data value**. For this problem can I use **`GooglePushNotification`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use GCM to implement this. You can follow below algorithm.

1. There will be an application on each android device which will register to GCM and send the registration ID to Server.
2. Whenever any data is changed, Android app will send that data to server.
3. Server will keep data with itself and send GCM tickle to all registered devices.
4. Once Push notification is received, each android client will communicate with Server to get latest data.
5. Just in-case device misses the GCM tickle, you can retry fetching latest data from server on each Network toggle.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Hope This Helps!